# Can't add new cobra CLI command when the file is inside a folder

Tags: go, command, go-cobra

I am using cobra to build CLI.
I want to create a new command called `config` that will be inside the file `config.go` and the file inside the folder `proxy`.

This is the structure:

```
MyProject
├── cmd
|  ├── proxy
|  |    └── config.go
|  └── root.go
└── main.go
```

I created the command with cobra:

```
cobra add config
```

It created the file under `cmd` and I moved the file to be under the `proxy` folder (as appeared in the structure above).

The problem is that the command is not being added.
This is `config.go` code:

```
// config.go
package cmd

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
    "MyProject/cmd"
)

var configCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "config",
    Short: "A brief description.",
    Long: `A longer description.`,
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        fmt.Println("config called")
    },
}

func init() {
    cmd.RootCmd.AddCommand(configCmd)
}
```

It build successfully but I don't see the command when I run `MyProj.exe -h`.
Am I doning something wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package is not included in the build, so the command never initializes.

Go builds packages. When you build the `cmd` package, all go files in that package will be compiled, and all the `init()` functions will be called. But if there's nothing referencing to the `proxy` package, it will not be compiled.

Your proxy package has `package cmd` in it, so that package is a `cmd` package under proxy directory. You should rename that to `proxy` package.

Then, include it in the build. In main.go:

```
import {
  _ "github.com/MyProject/cmd/proxy"
}
```

This will cause the `init()` for that package to run, and it will add itself to the command.

Comment: Saved me from a huge headache, thank you!